# Replacing TransferHandler implementation in JTextArea breaks Ctrl+C - WHY?

Tags: java, swing

In order to manage the "drop" of a file into a `JTextArea`, in the constructor of a `JPanel` I do this:

```
TransferHandler transferHandler = new DecoderTransferHandler();
requestTextArea.setTransferHandler(transferHandler);
```

`DecoderTransferHandler` is an inner class of the `JPanel`

```
class DecoderTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
        if(support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor))
                return true;
        return super.canImport(support);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
        try {
            if(!canImport(support))
                return false;

            List<File> files = (List<File>) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            if (files.isEmpty())
                return super.importData(support);

            // etc...

            validate();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showError(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm except Ctrl+C does not work anymore for this particular JTextArea (`requestTextArea`)... WHY?

Comment: I believe cut/copy/paste is handled by the TransferHandler. You are are replacing the TransferHandler so you lose the default implementaton. Check out the Swing tutorial on [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html),

Comment: All subclasses of JTextComponent, including JTextArea, install their own [subclass of TransferHandler](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.java#L4034).  Your subclass will probably need to delegate all methods which you otherwise wouldn’t override to that default TransferHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do here is not to implement a `TransferHandler` but rather to subclass `DropTarget` and replace that. Redefine only the method(s) that you want to customize. Drag and drop gestures with text still work as before.

```
requestTextArea.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(){
    @Override
    public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        try {
            if(!dtde.getCurrentDataFlavorsAsList().isEmpty() &&
                    dtde.getCurrentDataFlavorsAsList().get(0).getHumanPresentableName().equals("application/x-java-file-list")) {
                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                List<File> files = (List<File>) dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                
                // use files...
                
                dtde.dropComplete(true);

                validate();
            }
            else
                super.drop(dtde);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showError(e);
            dtde.dropComplete(false);
        }
    }
});
```